# Alternatives to Matlab - Running Matlab code in Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, matlab

I have to run some Matlab scripts on Raspberry Pi. As per my understanding, Matlab is quite heavy and cannot be installed on Raspberry Pi. Are there any other safe alternatives? My Matlab code does not require Simulink and it involves simple matrices operations. I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could try installing [GNU Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/). It's more-or-less compatible with Matlab, so you can run those scripts without rewriting them.

Alternatively, you could rewrite your code in Python, using numpy library for your matrices.

Comment: Is Octave lightweight, have not used it before?

Comment: It will run slower compared to a proper desktop computer, but it will run your code. You need to test your own script, if its memory and speed fits your application, it's all right. But I don't have your script to test. Also, my 1B+ machine is relatively weak to contemporary RPis and clones.

Comment: Many Thanks. Mine is 3 B. So I am assuming it would work fine.